# Is creating a fictional setting haram?

Tags: halal-haram, shirk

I want to write a fictional story that is set in a fictional setting created by me. It's a fantasy story, but it does ***not*** have things like magic. It simply has multiple sapient races (Dwarves, Elves, Humans) set in a fictional continent. Is this shirk? I am not creating ***any*** new religions. I have a disclaimer that everything in the novel is completely false.

Comment: A relevant hadith: https://sunnah.com/adab/21/3.

Comment: anyone please give a more detailed answer

Answer (score 1):

Lying: Telling false statements and leading others to believe they are true

Fiction: Expressing your imagination by telling imaginative stories.The readers/listeners know that this didn't happen and that it's fiction.

Lying involves deception,fiction does not.For fiction to involve lying,you have to state that that story happened and that it is real

http://www.understanding-islam.com/is-writing-fiction-forbidden-in-islam/
https://islamqa.info/en/163469

I hope this is enough to clear your doubts about this matter

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking our [tour] and checking our [help].

Comment: Thank you. However, it is more the "Creating" part that concerns me. I know that I cannot create anything and the only creator is Allah, but I am still concerned.

Comment: You are overthinking it, just like me when i was younger. As far as creating is concerned,i think it only involves living beings (and images of living beings),not imagination and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

As a writer myself I have heard from another Muslim writer that they try best to not mention any form of fictional religion. You can write stories but just be wary of promoting bad things within them. Especially if it a fantasy genre story don't incorporate anything about Islam or Muslims within it. Sorry for posting this in the answers section